# How can I get batch physicochemical properties for molecule names?

Tags: knime, chemistry

Normally I use Chemspider webservice client (WSDL) with the help of Knime generic web service clients to convert a list of molecule names into a table containing molecular properties (physicochemical prperties,...). Now, Chemspider has suspended its WSDL function and I don't know how to get these data.
I've tried using ChemBL, but the Get request function of uploaded workflows don't work.
Are there any remaining ways (free)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about data, not programming. You could try asking on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I myself use pubchempy module for this purpose. It's really easy to handle,  and I find it more flexible and easier than chem spider for general use.